# Villager Logic Puzzle Alternative Answer

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, puzzle

**Question:** Each inhabitant of a remote village always tells the truth
or always lies.A villager will give only a “Yes” or a “No”
response to a question a tourist asks. Suppose you are a
tourist visiting this area and come to a fork in the road.
One branch leads to the ruins you want to visit; the other
branch leads deep into the jungle. A villager is standing
at the fork in the road. What one question can you ask the
villager to determine which branch to take?

I was wondering if the following question to the villager would tell me if the right branch for example would take me to the ruins I want.

**You are Truthful if and only if the right branch is the correct branch to the ruins, correct?.**

What I tried here is to make a truth table. Let $p$ denote the proposition that the villager is truthful and $q$ denote that the right branch is the correct branch. My question should basically be equivalent to $p \Leftrightarrow q?$

$p\quad \quad q \quad \quad p \Leftrightarrow q \quad \quad Response $

$T \quad \quad T \quad \quad T \quad \quad \quad \quad Yes$

$T \quad \quad F \quad \quad F  \quad \quad \quad \quad No$

$F \quad \quad T \quad \quad F   \quad \quad \quad \quad$ **Yes**

$F \quad \quad F \quad \quad T    \quad \quad \quad \quad$ **No**

The truthful villager would answer $p \Leftrightarrow q$ truthfully always, however, a liar villager would answer $\neg (p \Leftrightarrow q)$. In either ways, I hear Yes whenever the right branch is actually the direction I want (i.e when q is true).

Is there any flaws in this answer?

Comment: If I am truthful, I am truthful regardless of the the direction that the right branch points.  So as a truthful person I would answer "No" regardless of the direction the path goes.

Comment: But the proposition is saying you are truthful if and only if the branch is correct. If it is not then a $T \Leftrightarrow F = T \quad iff \quad F$ Which is false. So he would say No as in No not correct on my statement.

Comment: What Doug M is saying is that "if and only if" doesn't mean in natural English what it means in propositional logic. In natural English, it implies some sort of causation between the concepts involved. A more faithful translation of the sentiment you're going for might be **Is the truth value of 'you are truthful' the same as that of 'the right branch leads to the ruins'?**

Comment: That's okay.  But it opens the whole "does if then imply causality" discussion.  There is an easier answer.  But that's a correct answer.

Comment: If I'm truthful, I'm truthful regardless of where the road goes. The means if the road goes to the ruins then I am truthful is true.  But I am only truthful if the road goes to the ruins is only true if the road goes to the ruins.

Comment: @Reese English isn't my first language so I am sorry if it was not that clear, thats why I tried to write the math to avoid confusion. But Yes, I meant your last sentence.

Comment: @fleablood I am not that well versed on prop logic tbh, I just started reading a book yesterday so I am not so sure what you mean by "casuality", but I am guessing its sth debated on?

Comment: The statement "if it is raining then dragons eat cheese" in logic means "it is not the case that it is raining and dragons eat c

Comment: @fleablood Ahaa, even though it doesn't make sense really as an implication in real language, its an implication in prop logic. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I mean IMO you are right (using propositional logic) and in this case Doug is wrong (using natural language).  But the wording of if and only if can feel very wrong.  "The truth value" version will avoid issues.

Answer (score 0):

No. There are no flaws in the answer, assuming that the villager understands that "if and only if" implies a material equivalence relation rather than a pair of strict conditionals. See also the following discussion: 
Noah Schweber (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/28111/noah-schweber), Difference between biconditional and logical equivalence, URL (version: 2018-02-14): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2650472