# Difference between biconditional and logical equivalence

Tags: logic, terminology, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

A biconditional can also be stated as "P is equivalent to Q," whereas a logical equivalence can also be stated as "P is logically equivalent to Q." I never understood *intuitively* what the difference between them was. I *get* that biconditional is true when both P and Q are true or false, and logical equivalence means P and Q have all of the same possible truth values, but I cannot grasp *intuitively* what they really *mean* and what the difference between them is.

Comment: Basically, the [biconditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_biconditional) is a connective (a part of the language) while [logical equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence) is a semantical relation between formulas expressible in the meta-language. The two are strictly linked: $\vDash (\varphi \leftrightarrow \psi)$ iff ($\varphi \vDash \psi$ and $\psi \vDash \varphi$).

Comment: It may help to note that the language may have no biconditional connective but the relation of logical equivalence between formulas still exists.

Comment: See also this answer on SE Philosophy: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/65024/what-is-the-difference-between-logical-equivalence-and-material-equivalence

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference inbetween $\leftrightarrow$, $\iff$, and $\equiv$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3926367/what-is-the-difference-inbetween-leftrightarrow-iff-and-equiv)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Distinction between equality, logical equivalence and biconditionality.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500644/distinction-between-equality-logical-equivalence-and-biconditionality)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically, the distinction is between talking about a *specific situation* versus *all possible situations*.

---

Suppose I have two different [propositional variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_variable) $p$ and $q$. Then:

- $p$ and $p\wedge p$ are logically equivalent. *(Remember that "$\wedge$" means "and.")*
- $p$ and $q$ are not logically equivalent.
- However, $p\iff q$ might be true *(e.g. if both $p$ and $q$ happen to be true)*.

This is ultimately a distinction between talking about *general necessities* versus *specific situations*. The keyword here is "model." In the setting of propositional logic *(there are [other logics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic))*, a model is just a *specific assignment* of truth values to the propositional variables in the language. E.g. suppose our language has propositional atoms $p, q, r$. Then "$p$ and $q$ are true, $r$ is false" *(or rather, the function $\nu: \{p, q, r\}\rightarrow\{true, false\}$ sending $p$ and $q$ to $true$ and $r$ to $false$)* is a model. Note that given a model, we can also talk about the truth values of more complicated sentences in that model: e.g. "$p\wedge r$" is false according to the model above.

*(Indeed, we can prove by "structural induction" that an assignment of truth values to propositional variables uniquely extends to an assignment of truth values to all propositions, which respects the obvious rules - e.g. if $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are both assigned "true," then $\varphi\wedge\psi$ must be assigned "true," and so forth. Sometimes a model is defined as a truth assignment to all propositions, which satisfies these reasonable rules; the proof described in the previous sentence means that we can get away with the simpler definition above.)*

When we say that two sentences are logically equivalent, we mean that there is *no model in which they have different truth values*. The expression "$p\iff q$," however, is a (compound) sentence which is (in general) true in some models and false in others. This is the distinction:

- The notion of "logical equivalence" is talking about what things are possible *in general*.
- When we say that a sentence is true/false, we are talking about its truth/falsity *in a specific model*.

For example, in the model $\nu$ defined above the sentence "$p\iff q$" is true, even though $p$ and $q$ are not logically equivalent (exercise).

At this point, it's useful to introduce a bit of terminology: a sentence which is true in every model is called a [**tautology**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)). When we say "$\varphi$ and $\psi$ are logically equivalent," we're just saying "$\varphi\iff \psi$ is a tautology."

---

**A bit of more advanced material**

There is also a "relative" version of this. Suppose $\varphi$ is some proposition which is true in every model *in which the proposition $\psi$ is also true*. *(Note that this just means that the proposition "$\psi\implies\varphi$" is a tautology.)* Then we write "$\psi\models\varphi$."

The value of this new symbol is that it lets us generalize considerably: if $\Gamma$ is a *set* of propositions, we write "$\Gamma\models\varphi$" iff $\varphi$ is true in every model where *every* proposition in $\Gamma$ is true. If $\Gamma$ is infinite, this is meaningfully different from just talking about tautologies *(since "$\Gamma\implies\varphi$" isn't actually a proposition)*.

However, one of the most important theorems in logic - the [compactness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem) - states that if $\Gamma\models\varphi$ then there is some *finite subset* $\{\gamma_1, \gamma_2,...\gamma_n\}\subseteq\Gamma$ such that $\{\gamma_1, \gamma_2,...,\gamma_n\}\models\varphi$. And *this* just means that the proposition "$(\gamma_0\wedge\gamma_1\wedge...\wedge\gamma_n)\implies\varphi$" is a tautology. So *via the compactness theorem* we can reduce questions about the relation "$\models$" to questions about tautologies, but that's far from obvious.

(And there are important logics which *don't* have this property, so actually they are meaningfully different in general.)

Answer (score 3):

Think of the material biconditional $\LARGE\leftrightarrow$ as a logical operation on two sentences rather than as *equivalence*. Unlike the latter, it is not making an assertion nor in a metalangauge.

- The statement $\Large P\equiv Q$ asserts the **logical equivalence** of $P$ and $Q.$ It means that $\large P\leftrightarrow Q$ is a (logical) validity, i.e., is true regardless of interpretation.

  [What's the difference between $↔$ and $≡$ ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2432462/21813)
- The statement $\Large P {\iff} Q$ asserts the (not necessarily logical) **equivalence** of $P$ and $Q.$ This means that that $\large P \leftrightarrow Q$ is either analytically (in an axiom system) or synthetically true , i.e., that $P$ and $Q$ have the same truth value in the given interpretation.

  $\Large P {\iff} Q$ can be read as ‘$P$ is true if and only if $Q$ is true’ or ‘$P$ being true is a necessary and sufficient condition for $Q$ to be true’.

For example, the sentences $\:0=0\:$ and $\:3^2=9\:$ are mathematically but not logically equivalent.

P.S. Symbolic logic is an area rife with conflicting notation, terminology and even notions; my understanding is eclectically evolving.

Answer (score -1):

Logical equivalence is typically defined using the biconditional, so that A <=> B if and only if A => B and B => A.

However, logical equivalence as so defined may differ from a mathematical equivalence. A mathematical equivalence relation defined on a certain domain is one that is 1) reflexive ( A <=> A), 2) symmetric, (if A <=> B, then B <=> A), and 3) transitive. (if A <=> B and B <=> C, then A <=> C). A mathematical equivalence relation then divides its domain into equivalence classes. As applied to propositions, these classes are typically "true", and "false".

In classical two-valued logic, these definitions coincide, so that logical equivalence is also a mathematical equivalence and does signify that two propositions have the same truth value.
In multivalued logics, with few exceptions, logical equivalence as defined by the biconditional is not a mathematical equivalence.