# notation for equivalence of boolean algebra expressions

Tags: notation, boolean-algebra

I am a bit puzzled about the semantics of the $\iff$ notation. I understand clearly its meaning in a logical prepositions context. However, $\iff$ can also be understood as a boolean algebra operator with its own truth table: $ T \iff T = T, T \iff F = F, etc$

This is somewhat unusual as one is typically accustomed to think of operators like $\land$ , (boolean AND), $\lor$ (boolean OR), $\oplus$ (boolean XOR) etc. when talking about boolean operations. But, like I said $\iff$ can also viewed as an binary boolean operator with its own truth table.

Therein lies the conundrum: how do I express notationally, e.g. that $A \iff B$ is equivalent to $A \implies B \land B \implies A$ ?

If I were to write:

$ (A \iff B) \iff [(A \implies B) \land (B \implies A)]$

Then I think the notation is problematic as it uses the same symbol ($\iff$) with two different semantics / nuances:

- the first instance of $\iff$ uses it as a boolean algebra operation
- the second instance of $\iff$ uses it to convey the idea of logical equivalence

It also seems somewhat cyclical.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, there is the need to have two symbols: one for the propositional connective called [bi-conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_biconditional): it is part of the *formal language*, like the negation operator $\lnot$, and it is used to produce *formulas*, and the other one for the relation of [(logical) equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence) between formulas, that is "outside" the language (the meta- context). Unfortunately, there is no common agreed convention about the use of the available symbols: $\leftrightarrow, \Leftrightarrow, \equiv$.

Comment: The simplest approach is: to explicitly define a "convention" when you start your "text" and use it consistently.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I am glad I wasn't just over-analyzing this.

Comment: Some years ago, when I used a implication operation (in the context of Boolean or Heyting algebras, and more generally residuated lattices, and perhaps even more general settings, I don't remember right...) I used $\to$ for the operation symbol, and $\Rightarrow$ for the implication between formulas, and I always felt confused about the use of $\Rightarrow$ as an operation symbol, but it happens; as Mauro Allegranza wrote, there is no agreement about this notation...

Comment: Here is my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3884854/21813) to your question, and [its counterpart](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4251001/21813) for → ⇒ ⊨ ⊢.