# How would you represent exponents in predicate logic statements?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

So I've seen simpler logic statements that are translated into English, but for this one, how exactly could this be represented?

> "For any positive number, there exists a second number, the square of
> which is equal to the first number."

In predicate logic, could you add exponents? Something like this?

$$(\forall A) \,\,(\exists B) \,\,B^2 \equiv A$$

Given that $A$ is the first integer and $B$ is the second. Or do they even need to be 2 separate variables?

Comment: If the exponent function *has been* defined for the domain, then you may use it.  [Has it?]

Comment: Nope. All that was given was the question itself, nothing extraneous. If you can't use it, then how would you translate the statement into predicate logic?

Comment: What predicate or function symbols *do* you have? But if nothing is given to you, then what you have is probably just fine…. You often see this mix of logic and math notation. Though I would use a normal = symbol

Comment: Again, nothing else was given haha. The A and B variables were made up by my own accord, they could have very well been C and D. Will change the equal sign though, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\forall a: \forall b: [N(a) \land N(b) \implies [S(a,b) \iff M(a,a,b)]] $

Where the predicates $N,M$ and $S$ can be interpreted as follows:

$~~~~~N(x)~~~~~~~~~~\equiv ~~$"$x$ is a number"

$~~~~~M(x,y,z)~~\equiv~~ x\cdot y =z$

$~~~~~S(x,y)~~~~~~~\equiv ~~ x\cdot x = y$

Answer (score 1):

1. > "For any positive number, there exists a second number, the square of which is equal to the first number."
   > $$(\forall A) \,\,(\exists B) \,\,B^2 \equiv A$$
   >
   > do $A$ and $B$ even need to be 2 separate variables?

   Yes, here, $A$ and $B$ are required to be separate variables.
2. > could you add exponents, like this?

   Am I correct in guessing that you made up the exercise?

   In symbolic/formal logic (which is algorithmic/programmable by
   design), a statement consists not only of logical symbols like
   $\forall$ and $\to,$ but also non-logical symbols (which depend on
   the "language" and "model" that we are working in), e.g.,
   arithmetical symbols like $0$ and $+.\quad$ My model may for example have
   $\#$ as a binary arithmetical operator (like $+$ is) such that
   $B\#2$ means $B^2.$

   Note that mathematical writing containing symbolic statements like
   $$\forall \epsilon>0\;\exists \delta > 0\;\forall
   x\;\big(|x-x_0|<\delta\implies|f(x)-a| < \epsilon\big),$$ is not
   *formal* logic.
3. The meaning of the symbol $\equiv$ depends on the text/context, and
   I like to use it *meta*logically to mean [logical equivalence](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3884854/21813) (i.e., a biconditional
   $(\leftrightarrow)$ statement that is true regardless of what its
   non-logical symbols mean). In contrast, the equality relation $=$ is
   actually a standard logical symbol, which ought to be used instead of
   the $\equiv$ in your suggested statement.
4. The parentheses around $\forall A$ and $\exists B$ are redundant; on
   the other hand, parentheses are required when the quantification is
   meant to apply beyond its minimum construeable scope. So,
   $$\forall x\;(x=0\to x=0')\\\not\equiv(\forall x \;\,x=0\to
   x=0')\\\equiv\forall x \;\,x=0\to
   x=0'\\\equiv(\forall x\;\, x=0)\to x=0'\\\equiv(\forall x)\; x=0\to
   x=0'.$$