# What does $\Leftrightarrow$ Mean?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

What does $\Leftrightarrow$ Mean?

I know that in set theory the notation $\Leftrightarrow$ usually means “if and only if” however recently I’ve seen lots of modal logic statements written I such a way that they use the symbols $\Leftrightarrow$ and $\equiv$ synonymously. So can someone please explain what does $\Leftrightarrow$ mean in modal logic.

Comment: $$A \iff B$$ is exactly equivalent to the compound statement $$(A \implies B) ~~~\text{and}~~~ (B \implies A).$$

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3884854/21813) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4465471/21813) is a perspective (well, mine).

Comment: You need to cite a specific text that is causing you a problem. There is no general agreement about the usage of these symbols and nothing specific to modal logic AFAIK.